# Oracle xe 11g in docker, users created are lost after restarting docker on ubuntu

Tags: oracle, docker, ubuntu

I have installed **docker** on **Ubuntu 21.10** and following the official
[instructions](https://hub.docker.com/r/oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g)  I pulled **oracle 11g xe** image:

`docker pull oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g`

Then I started the image:

`docker run -d -p 49161:1521 -p 8080:8080 oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g`

and using the **Oracle SQL Developer** I connected as **SYSTEM** and created a standard user, granting the appropriate privileges (create/delete tables, sequences etc).

Then I connected as that standard user and started creating and populating some tables.

But when stopping the docker image and restarting it, the user and all the tables were lost. What could be done to resolve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a volume in order to keep persistent data. Moreover, once you start to deal with those kind of things. It is better to deal using docker compose.

**Option 1 using docker**:

First create the volume:

```
docker volume create db-vol
```

Then use this command in order to attach the volumen where the data is stored:

```
docker run -d -p 49161:1521 -p 8080:8080 -v db-vol:/opt/oracle/oradata oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g
```

**Option 2 using docker compose**:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  oracle-db:
    image: oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g:latest
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
      - 5500:5500
    volumes:
      - db-vol:/opt/oracle/oradata
volumes:
 db-vol:
```

Please, find the theory of the concepts needed here:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

https://hub.docker.com/r/oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g

Comment: This solution also work on ACI